# PyDev rewrites my .pydevproject

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse - 3.7

Pydev - 2.6

I use PyDev for Eclipse and I have several dependencies on my project. I **DO NOT WANT** to add them manually to PyDev using the UI. Instead I have a script that prints

```
<path>...library...</path>
```

When I edit the .pyproject and add these elements eclipse seems to resync the project to says "resource is out of sync" and when I refresh I get the empty .pyproject file.

It happens in only one project though. Why does this happen and how do I edit it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was totally my fault. The giveaway was that this only happened in one project. The script I created for generating the .pydev project file was an invalid XML file (some closing fragment was missing)

May be we could have a feature to check if a given xml is valid and alert the user. The "resource out of sync" message did not make this clear at all